# OnDelete Handler always trigger a bad request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Trying to be more consistent with HTTP verbs, I'm trying to call a delete Handler on a Razor Page via AJAX;

Here's my AJAX code, followed by the C# code on my page :

```
return new Promise(function (resolve: any, reject: any) {
  let ajaxConfig: JQuery.UrlAjaxSettings =
  {
    type: "DELETE",
    url: url,
    data:  JSON.stringify(myData),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { resolve(data); },
    error: function (data) { reject(data); }

  };

  $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
});
```

my handler on my cshtml page :

```
public IActionResult OnDeleteSupprimerEntite(int idEntite, string infoCmpl)
{
    // my code
}
```

which never reaches ... getting a `bad request` instead !

When I switch to a 'GET' - both the type of the ajax request and the name of my handler function ( `OnGetSupprimerEntite` ) - it does work like a charm.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: The `400 bad request` indicates the request doesn't fulfill the server side's needs.

---

Firstly, your server is expecting a **form** by;

```
public IActionResult OnDeleteSupprimerEntite(int idEntite, string infoCmpl)
{
  // my code
}
```

However, you're sending the payload in **`application/json`** format.

Secondly, when you sending a form data, don't forget to add a **csrf token**:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf

<script>
    function deleteSupprimerEntite(myData){
        var url = "Index?handler=SupprimerEntite";
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            let ajaxConfig = {
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                data: myData ,
                success: function (data) { resolve(data); },
                error: function (data) { reject(data); }
            };
            $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
        })
    }
    document.querySelector("#testbtn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
        var myData ={
            idEntite:1,
            infoCmpl:"abc",
            __RequestVerificationToken: "@(Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken)",
        };
        deleteSupprimerEntite(myData);
    });
</script>
```

**A Working Demo:**

[image]

---

Finally, in case you want to send in **json format**, you could change the server side Handler to:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int idEntite {get;set;}
    public string infoCmpl{get;set;}
}

public IActionResult OnDeleteSupprimerEntite([FromBody]MyModel xmodel)
{
    return new JsonResult(xmodel);
}
```

And the js code should be :

```
function deleteSupprimerEntiteInJson(myData){
    var url = "Index?handler=SupprimerEntite";
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let ajaxConfig = {
            type: "DELETE",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(myData) ,
            contentType:"application/json",
            headers:{
                "RequestVerificationToken": "@(Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken)",
            },
            success: function (data) { resolve(data); },
            error: function (data) { reject(data); }
        };
        $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    })
}

document.querySelector("#testbtn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var myData ={
        idEntite:1,
        infoCmpl:"abc",
    };
    deleteSupprimerEntiteInJson(myData);
});
```